Running an application installed with msix via command line
Is there a way to use the command line to launch an application installed via an msix file?
It's certainly not intuitive, but I found a partial answer in: https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/how-to-open-microsoft-store-apps-from-command-prompt/
For your own application for which you've created an msix install, it's a little easier than for a random msix-installed app, which is what the link above goes into. The command line to launch an msix-installed app without command line arguments is:
explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\<PackageFamilyName>!<App ID>

PackageFamilyName can be found in the 'Packaging' tab of the 'Package.appxmanifest' in the UI (but not in the actual Package.appxmanifest file). App ID can be found the actual Package.appxmanifest file (but not in any of the UI tabs).
However, this doesn't work when adding command line arguments.
It looks like command line launching of msix-installed applications is not encouraged.
If this isn't possible, is there a work-around? The underlying application being packaged is a WinForms application.

Got around this by producing separate console app versions.

The correct way to execute an application installed by an MSIX via the command line is to declare an app execution alias inside the MSIX package.
Here are more details and an example:
https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-environment-variables.html

Thanks Bogdan - this process is not as simple as I'd like. I've decided to produce separate console applications.
